# Obtain local time with javascript and check if it is GMT 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to somehow check local time of the machine accessing the website and compare it to GMT 0, so I can alert users if they need to change time.

Comment: you mean the GMT-0 time zone? you can't require users to change their time if they're in a different timezone...

Comment: @MarcB This application is for my personal use, users here refer to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in JS with Date.getTimezoneOffset

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: The only thing to be aware of here is that this assumes a user has their date/time/timezone set correctly. Small caveat, but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

Date getTimezoneOffset shall do it for you.

```
var x=new Date();
x.getTimezoneOffset()
```